# How to close an Idea so that no one can vote for it

Tags: schedulebatch, ideas

I am working on a POC, where we need to convert the Ideas into a Case.

Once an Idea reaches, let us say 100 points ( assuming each person’s vote is 10 points ), the idea should gets converted to a Case with the record type  `Enhancement` and the status of the Idea changes to `"Under Consideration"`.

If the Idea is below 100 points, it should have the status `"Under Point Threshold"`.

I have implemented this logic.
I want to know how to close an idea that is converted into Case, so that no one can vote on those delivered/converted Ideas?

Any pointers will be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What process did you use to create your case from the idea?

Comment: I have used Process Builder to create Case from an Idea. Also, I have developed a Schedule and a Batch class to get the Ideas which satisfy the below condition and change their status.

• Idea would need to have at least 50 points (Vote Total >= 50). 
• Idea should be in the “Under Point Threshold” status.